# Create a react native app with javascript instead of typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native, init

I recently tried to crate a new react native app by using the `

npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

`
command but it created a folder with a app.tsx file.

How can I force it to create a app.js instead? Or can I just replace it with a javascript file? I can't find an awnser to this so hopefully someone can help me.

Greetings

Ben

Comment: Same question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146894/why-react-native-project-is-creating-in-typescript-i-want-app-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React native of `>=0.71` version considers Typescript as default. You can change the `.tsx` file to the `.js` file by changing the file extension and deleting the typescript codes from the file.

But react-native `<=0.70` version still considers JavaScript as default. To install react native of `<=0.70` you can use the following command on CLI:

```
npx react-native init <project_name> --version 0.70
```

Here you can write the version you want.

Official Reference: [Using JavaScript Instead of TypeScript](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript)